# Match number if greater than zero

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm using the following `PCRE` expression with `preg_match` to check if the value I want is a digit or not.

```
(?P<id>[\d]+)
```

It works, but now I want it to match the same conditions except if the whole content equals `0` (zero).

**Example result**

```
1    valid
10   valid
0    invalid
```

**Expression context**

```
#^(?P<controller>.*?|home)(?:/(?P<action>.*?|index)(?:/(?P<id>[\d]+))?)?$#uD
```

Comment: Please post the entire expression too. Also, your question is quite unclear. Could you please give an example on what kind of string this would be applied to, what the desired outcome is, and what the current outcome is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
#^(?P<controller>home)(?:/(?P<action>index)(?:/(?P<id>[1-9][\d]*))?)?$#uD
```

In your example, just using the digits, it's matching  first, so obviously 0 gets captured. Assuming your match string is more complex than that, in which case the "1-9 once and 0-9 0 or more times" should do it for you.

See: http://regex101.com/r/yK6mR5

Comment: Doesn't work, validates even characters it's not supposed to.

Comment: @yoda you'll need to provide some samples to match then because your first <controller> capture matches everything (albeit non-greedy).

Comment: I am aware of that, you can test it with `a/b/0`

Comment: and the expected output is controller:a, index:b, id:0 ?

Comment: The problem is that IF it validates (as in, it's a 1) it works. If it's a 0 though, your previous capture <action> includes it in the result, hence why you're seeing two captures. Opinion: rethink this entire thing; split it on `/` and validate each segment. If segment(2) evaluates to 0, it's invalid. If it's > 0, you're good to go.

Comment: yes. I managed to do with from your example `([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,})`, after I forced the first 2 segments to match an exact string.

Comment: Right - that would work. Wasn't sure if you could do that in your scenario or not. You also don't need the explicit lengths like that (`[1-9]` will only match 1 char, `[0-9]*` matches 0 or more. Still, where this falls short is if you have `000000001` - it'll be a false negative.

Comment: @anubhava's got it fixed for you.. it works given your criteria.

Comment: The final expression, if you care to update your answer : `#^(?P<controller>home)(?:/(?P<action>index)(?:/(?P<id>[1-9][\d]*))?)?$#uD`

Comment: Updated. Just to clarify, that will ONLY work for the path `home/index` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!0+$)(?P<id>\d+)$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dB2eT3

**UPDATE:**

Working regex:

```
'#^(?P<controller>[^/]*|home)(?:/(?P<action>[^/]*|index)(?:/(?!0+$)(?P<id>\d+))?)?$#'
```

Comment: Can you clarify why this cannot work, see this demo link: http://regex101.com/r/nY6nV9

Comment: considering the value as integer, I don't want it to have leading zeros or the whole value as zero, so any number above zero.

Comment: Yes that's what it is doing, did you check the demo? It allows any number greater than 0.

Comment: It only works out of context, the subpattern `<id>` is not being used.

Comment: Once again I will suggest looking at linked demo I provided. In both cases of positive numbers `<id>` is being populated (shown on right hand side).

Comment: `#^(?P<controller>.*?|home)(?:/(?P<action>.*?|index)(?:/(?!0+$)(?P<id>[\d]+))?)?$#uD` does not work.

Comment: What is the input string for that regex?

Comment: That is because your regex is wrong esp. where you use `.*?` See working code demo: http://regex101.com/r/gR2bS8